# Volume of the intersection of unit hypercube and Lp n-ball

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

What is the $n$-dimensional volume of the intersection of a unit hypercube (side length 1) and an $L_p$ ball with radius $r$, both centered at the origin, with $p > 0$? [This includes the $L_p$ seminorms where $0 < p < 1$].

This question is a generalization of [intersection of hypercube and hypersphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996000/intersection-of-hypercube-and-hypersphere). I am wondering if there is an analytical and/or recursive solution similar to the accepted answer there, which is given for the specific case when $p = 2$. The question is also similar to [volume of the intersection of two lp balls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084555/volume-of-the-intersection-of-two-lp-balls), which does not have an accepted answer, though my question has different constraints and may be easier to solve analytically.

When $r \geq \frac{1}{2}||\mathbf{1}||_p$, the hypercube will be contained within the $L_p$ ball and the volume $V$ will be 1. When $r \leq \frac{1}{2}$, then the ball will be contained within the hypercube and

$V = 2^n r^n \frac{\Gamma\left(1 + \frac{1}{p}\right)^n}{\Gamma\left( 1 + \frac{n}{p} \right)}$,

where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function, as shown [here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/07/02/volumes-of-generalized-unit-balls/) but scaled by $r^n$ for non-unit balls.

What is the volume when $\frac{1}{2} < r < \frac{1}{2}||\mathbf{1}||_p$?

Comment: The recursion (following the accepted answer literally) is $$V_n(r)=2\int_0^{\min\{r,1/2\}}V_{n-1}\big((r^p-x^p)^{1/p}\big)~dx,\qquad V_0(r)\equiv 1.$$

Comment: Thanks @metamorphy! That was much more straightforward than I anticipated. I am curious if there's a way to represent it analytically with the gamma function, as that recursion seems very similar to that used in the derivation of [Lp ball volume](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~hyx/0423/Volume_of_an_n-ball.pdf). This would likely need $n + 1$ formulas, depending on the size of $r$, but I'm struggling to factor the recursive element out of the integral. (Something like $V_n(r) = 2 V_{n - 1}(f(r)) \int ...$).